# May I factorize more the header I'm creating at the top of my markdown documents? It has constant parts, but also variables ones

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I have organized the generation of my markdown documents that way:

```
export APPRENTISSAGE_HOME=the folder where my documents are

/apprentissage
    gen.sh : a script running a command: 'pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures 
             --syntax-definition=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/java.xml 
             "${source}".md -o "${source}".pdf'
        → gen e020-analyse generates a e020-analyse.pdf from a e020-analyse.md file

    apprentissage-header-include.tex: \usepackage, \DeclareUnicodeCharacter directives
        \usepackage{fvextra}
        \usepackage{mathtools}
        \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{3C3}{\text{$\sigma$}}
        \DisableLigatures[-]{}

    apprentissage-include.tex: definitions of custom commands or colors
        \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}
        \setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}

        \newcommand{\suspect}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor{gray}{#1}}}
        \newcommand{\fonction}[1]{\begingroup\small\mauve{\texttt{#1}}\endgroup}
        \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Contenu}

        \definecolor{cadreCodeBackground}{RGB}{130,124,106}
        \newcommand{\cadreCode}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=cadreCodeBackground!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,lowerbox=invisible,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=0cm}}}}

    /informatique this folder and the next have about 30 markdowns file inside
    /mathematiques
    /statistiques
    /analyse_spatiale
    /territoire
```

To work, each of my markdown files are starting the way below, and I would like to improve the the part between the `---` and `---`:

```
---
header-includes:
  \input{$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-header-include}
  \input{$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-include}

title: "e020. Analyse textuelle"
subtitle: ""
category: analyse textuelle

keywords:
- TF
- term frequency
- IDF
- inverse difference frequency
- mot
- ponctuation
- token

author: Marc Le Bihan
geometry: margin=1.5cm
fontsize: 12pt
output: pdf
classoption: fleqn
urlcolor: blue
---

Indexation des mots. La qualité de la recherche vient par l'emploi de deux indicateurs :

   - __TF__ (Term Frequency) : fréquence des mots.
[...]
```

In the part between `---` separators, I have two types of contents:

- One that is "static" to me: `author`, `geometry`, `fontsize`, `output`, `classoption`, `urlcolor` and

  ```
  header-includes:
     \input{$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-header-include}
     \input{$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-include}
  ```

  never changes, at the top of files.
- `title`, `subtitle`, `category`, `keywords` that are changing from file to file.

---

I would like to factorize more that part. Because it happens (whatever I've said) that I have sometimes to change that "static" part... And then, it's long to achieve: all the markdown files need edition and to have their *pdf* regenerated.

- May I dispatch some of the keywords `author`, `geometry`, `fontsize`, `output`, `classoption`, `urlcolor` or `header-includes:` in one of the include `.tex` file I've created, and how?
- Or should I improve my `gen.sh` running `pandoc` some way?
- Can another feature of *Latex* I haven't used yet, help me?

Answer (score 0):

A part of markdown document options can be transferred to a `metadata.json` file that Pandoc can include.

```yaml
geometry: margin=1.5cm
fontsize: 12pt
classoption: fleqn
urlcolor: blue
```

**metadata.json:**

```json
{
  "geometry": "margin=4cm",
  "fontsize": "12pt",
  "classoption": "fleqn",
  "urlcolor": "blue"
}
```

with the Pandoc command adding a `--metadata-file` inside:

```bash
pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures \
  --syntax-definition=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/java.xml \
  --metadata-file=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/metadata.json \
  s600-la_fouille_de_données.md -o s600-la_fouille_de_données.pdf
```

I can also move my header includes:

```yaml
header-includes:
  \input{$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-header-include}
  \input{$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-include}
```

to the Pandoc command:

```bash
pandoc -f markdown-implicit_figures \
  --syntax-definition=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/java.xml \
  --metadata-file=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/metadata.json \
  --include-in-header=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-header-include.tex \
  --include-in-header=$APPRENTISSAGE_HOME/apprentissage-include.tex \
  s600-la_fouille_de_données.md -o s600-la_fouille_de_données.pdf
```

This leaves me with a markdown preamble completely specific to its purpose, I was searching for.

```
---
title: "e020. Analyse textuelle"
subtitle: ""
category: analyse textuelle

keywords:
- TF
- term frequency
- IDF
- inverse difference frequency
- mot
- ponctuation
- token

author: Marc Le Bihan
---
```